# Pages: How to expand comments by default?

Tags: ms-office, pages

I bought my wife a new iMac for Christmas and she's one of those people who fear change and anything different than what she's used to scares her to no end.

She's demanding Microsoft Office without even trying Pages. She has no real use for Office and Pages would be just fine for her but she's making every tiny excuse she can come up with why Office is better.

Now it's the comments in Pages. I don't use Pages at all so I don't know but is there a way to keep all comments open by default? She's complaining about the little square it makes instead of the bubble in Office.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep comments always on-screen by going into the menu bar and choosing **View** → **Show Comments Pane**.

This will open a sidebar with all her comments on the left.

Answer (score 0):

This function is within the `View` menu:

```
View > Show Comments
```

You might have found it pretty fast with:

```
Help > show comments
```